# URL Design for SSL-Secured SaaS Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application using the ASP.NET MVC platform, which will be exposed as a service over the web (the [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_Service) model).  I am trying to determine the best way to partition the URL namespace for each user account.  The application will need to be accessed securely via SSL, so my main concerns have been around coming up with a URL design that works well with SSL certificates.  Here are the options I have come up with. In each example **bob** and **jane** are two example user accounts:

### Option A: Each Account Has Unique Subdomain under Common Domain Name

e.g.

```
https://bob.example.com
https://jane.example.com
```

- This would require a wildcard SSL
  certificate (e.g. mapped to
  *.example.com) so each user can seamlessly access their account via
  SSL.  By seamless I mean without the
  web browser warning the user about
  SSL certificate problems.  The only
  drawback I can think of is that
  wildcard certs seem to be
  considerably more expensive than
  normal fixed domain certs.  The cost
  difference will certainly be
  negligible in grand scheme of
  things, but it is something I am
  keeping in mind if all else proves
  to be equal.

### Option B: Each Account has Unique Domain Name

e.g.

```
https://bobs-domain.com
https://domain-of-jane.com
```

- In this case, each user would have an SSL certificate tied
  to their domain names.  One big
  drawback I can think of is that our
  servers would have to maintain the
  private keys for all the users'
  certs, and we would have to design a
  system that allowed users to
  securely transmit their private keys
  to our servers.  Even if we had such
  a system, I feel it would be too
  much of a burden on users to have to
  acquire a certificate then submit
  the private keys to us.
- Alternatively, we could
  automatically issue and provision an
  SSL certificate for each user when
  they sign up, so they can start
  accessing their app via SSL without
  additional steps.  This would
  require that we become an issuer of
  SSL certificates, which I haven't
  looked into yet... likely we would
  be a reseller for some other big
  company like Verisign who
  specializes in this sort of thing.
- Despite the apparent pain of this
  approach, this option does enable
  some features that we may want to
  provide in the future, i.e. allowing
  user's to have their own branded
  version of the app accessed via
  their own company domain name.

### Option C: Each Account has Unique Subdirectory under Common Domain Name

e.g.

```
https://example.com/bob
https://example.com/jane
```

- From the perspective of SSL
  certificate maintenance, this is
  probably the best option.  We would
  only need one fixed domain SSL cert
  (e.g. example.com) which would be
  used by all users.
- Unfortunately this URL design does not work well
  with other aspects of our current
  application architecture, especially
  around load balancing.

### Need Feedback

My question to you all is: what option would you choose, and why?  I would especially love to hear real-world examples and experiences, but any other issues or concerns that I haven't already presented would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with A. This solution is not very expensive, it scales well and it does not limit you to go with custom domains, if you decide this later on.

Wildcard certificates used to be quite expensive, but today you could get them around 200 USD annually at [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/ssl/ssl.asp?ci=9039) or [RapidSSL](http://www.rapidssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/rapidssl/usd/wildcard-ssl-certificate.htm), which I think is pretty cheap. These certificates works in (almost) any browser, but they doesn't come with the validation, VeriSign provides. I don't know whether you need this.

If you go with option B, you have to purchase a certificate per user, but with a wildcard certificate, the certificate will be paid after a few sign-ups and the rest will be pure revenue.

Aside from this the solution is really simple to implement, which also is a strength.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like option B to me. It's the only one that seems to a) work with your architecture and b) work with your potential future goals. You can make the price of the SSL cert for the custom domains part of the start up cost for the service (or amortize the cost over the monthly charges).

I don't see a real difference between A and B, they're effectively identical save that you CAN use a wild card cert for A, you just don't HAVE to. Without the wild card aspect, A == B, the fact that they're all subdomains of example.com is coincidence.

Even with option A at the beginning, you have room later to expand to option B if that's the kind of service feature you'd like to offer your clients.

Answer (score 1):

Option B has a a lot of value for users and if I had the choice I'd go this route. Keep in mind that you can buy multi-domain ssl certificates / UCC and you can get up to 100 domains under one certificate. If there are other certs out there that allow more then 100 - let me know because we're building an SAAS model as well and having similar questions.

Comment: you might want to expand on why option 'B' over the others to make this a better answer. It's more of a comment at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You're right Will, A and B are the same.  However, I think that is true mainly from a coding perspective.  With either option, the web server will determine the account based on the host name in the HTTP header.  C is slightly different from a coding perspective because it would match the account based on the path under the domain name, and the ASP.NET MVC framework's URL routing capabilities would come in handy here.

From an administrative perspective each option is quite different.  With option A we would have to manage the subdomains... which we can do because our DNS provider has an API to manage host records.  With option B we would have to manage the private keys for all the different domain names, as I mentioned.

I'm guessing from the number of responses that this is not the best type of question to ask on this forum, probably because it is too open ended.  I was just hoping that someone who has been there and done that would chime in, mainly so I know if I'm even on the right track, as I've never designed a system like this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use secure.domain.com instead of certificate for www.domain or domain.com
I've seen many sites that use certificates for one of the options (either with or without the www prefix) and when the user uses the other (s)he gets prompted for certificate acceptance.

You could use user.domain.com for a non-secure site and when the user needs an SSL enabled section just use your main secure.domain.com/user/ .......

That's just an idea.

Slavi

Comment: .... Also having a subdomain you could *map* that subdomain to an already existing user domain down the road. Ref: blogger's service. you could setup blog.domain.com and just add an CNAME pointing to blogger/google.